# Saving data from a dropdownlist which is fetched from another table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am having some problems with Yii PHP Framework. I have two tables:  `teacher` and `student`. I also have two view pages: `teacherview.php` and `studentview.php`. The teacher name fetched from `tbl_teacher`  to `studentview.php` using following code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php // echo $form->labelEx($model,'teacher'); ?>
        <?php
        echo $form->labelEx($model,'teacher');
        $records = Teacher::model()->findAll();
        $list=CHtml::listData(Teacher::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('Teacher', $model,
               CHtml::listData($records,'id', 'name'),array('empty' => '(Select a name)'));?>
                  <?php echo $form->error($model,'teacher'); ?>


</div>
```

and trying to store teacher name into student table using following code.

```
public function actionStudentview()
{
    $model=new Student;
    if(isset($_POST['Student']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Student'];
        if($model->validate())
        {


            $model->save();
            $this->redirect($this->createUrl('teacher/studentview'));

            return;
        }
    }
    $this->render('studentview',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

but Its not working...please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you show your code ? \

Comment: oh, i see the problem

Comment: downvote cause its confusing.

Comment: Show us your code please. Your question is confusing.

Comment: Hi, @Sulthan,@aldrin27 here i made some changes in my question with my code

Answer (score 0):

In controller after
    `$model->attributes=$_POST['Student'];`
add
    `$model->teacher = $_POST['Teacher'];`

OR

Keep your controller code as it is and in view 
    `echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'teacher'CHtml::listData($records,'id', 'name'),array('empty' => '(Select a name)'));`

You can use either of one solution.

Let me know if you face any issue